# Bash escapes tilde and wildcards but not space

Tags: bash, escaping, filenames, space

(EDIT in solution with sed)

I have a list of filenames and directories, including tilde and wildcards. E.g.:

```
~/docs/file.*    
~/my docs/*.txt
...
```

I read the rows and pass them to a command (e.g. rsync):

```
while read ROW
do
   rsync $ROW /my/dest/
done < list.txt
```

The problem is handling with spaces in filenames. If I put $ROW in double quotes like this

```
rsync "$ROW" /my/dest/
```

of course bash doesn't escape the wildcards nor the tilde. But if I don't use quotes, the space breaks the row.

One possible solution is change IFS (carefully: the script is more complicated than the one I reported).
Another solution (thanks for the fix to Patrick Echterbruch) is to pre-escape spaces. However, the following code doesn't work for me:

```
while read ROW
do
    export NEWROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g') 
    echo "Value: $NEWROW"
    ls -1d $NEWROW
done < list.txt
```

Please note no quotes are passed to ls. The file "~/a b c/test.txt" exists, but I get:

```
Value: ~/saver/a\ b\ c/*.txt
ls: impossibile accedere a ~/saver/a\: Nessun file o directory
ls: impossibile accedere a b\: Nessun file o directory
ls: impossibile accedere a c/*.txt: Nessun file o directory
```

Seems like NEWROW is passed to ls as a string, so wildcards are not expanded but space keeps breaking the filename, though escaped.

Any tip?
Thanks.

Comment: Please see [this regarding tilde expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22.2BAH4.22).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the sed script you posted is not going to have any effect - the "search" and "replace" parts are the same.

What you could do could do:

```
ROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e "s/ /\\\\ /g")
```

or (better):

```
ROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
```

Latter example uses single quotes, so that the shell doesn't treat the backslash specially.

Concerning the second problem that arose: The special characters (like `~`) are expanded by bash when they are encountered in parameters to a program. They will not be expanded when storing them in a variable, nor will bash inspect and expand the contents of a variable when passing it as parameter to a command.

This is why `rsync $NEWROW ...` does not work - rsync receives the unmodified content of $NEWROW as first parameter and would then have to do shell-like expansion on it's own.

The only workaround I known of is to run the command in a subshell, ie:

```
ROW="~/a b c"
$NEWROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
bash -c "ls -ld $f"
```

This will cause the currently running bash to extract the variables content (i.e. `~/a\ b\ c` and pass it to the second shell it is about to invoke. This "inner" bash will receive the command along with the parameters and will then of course to parameter expansion.

Sorry for missing this point in the beginning, I focused only on the regex part of the question.

Found another possible solution: After converting the path using sed (e.g. `NEWROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')` try:

```
eval ls -ld $NEWROW
```

or
    eval rsync $NEWROW /other/path

This should work as well, without the performance impact of starting subshells.

//EDIT: Added missing `g` to the sed script

//EDIT: Added workaround for the pathname expansion problem

//EDIT: Addes eval solution

Comment: Were you able to run this on your local machine? I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly well. The command: ROW="my doc"; echo $ROW; ROW=$(echo $ROW | sed -e 's/ /\\ /'); echo $ROW returns two lines, one with a pure space, the other one with a backslash-escaped space. sed --version: GNU sed version 4.2

Comment: Then we are missing the final "g" to replace every occurrence of space and not only the first occurrence: 's/ /\\ /g'. Now I wonder how to skip spaces already escaped, but I think there are other questions about it.

Comment: @EugenioR: Right, thanks for pointing that out. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I wonder how much opening a subshell for every row is slower than changing IFS or doing something else.

Comment: Well, as I said: It's the only way *I* know of, there may be many, many more and I'd be glad id someone could show a more elegant way. As to performance impact: `time for ((i=0; $i < 10000; i=$i+1)); do echo $i > /dev/nul; done` -> real: 0.489s, `time for ((i=0; $i < 10000; i=$i+1)); do bash -c "echo $i > /dev/nul"; done` -> real: 16.183s. It's roughly 32 times faster without invoking a subshell...

Comment: I've inserted another solution at the very bottom of my answer. Using eval should be much faster than starting subshells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pipe the list to be rsync into a separate file, and execute it, like

```
while read ROW
do
  echo "rsync '$ROW' /my/dest/"
done < list.txt > rsync.txt

sh rsync.txt
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but probably a bit slow (esp. if expanded wildcards yield to lots of files).